# Changing from static date to changing date in Query & issue with Aggregate Function - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, aggregate-functions

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT Artist_no, SUM(purchasedate BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2012-07-31') / 
                  SUM(purchasedate BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-31')
FROM Sales
```

This successfully returns me the percentage of increases/decreases in sales within my table 'Sales' of CD's. However I wish to alter to code to instead list specific dates of July 2011 against July 2012, to instead do July of this year, against July of last year. I understand that running this new query now would obtain the same result, however i wish if you were to do this query in 100 years time, the query would test for July 2111 against July 2112.

I have attempted to do this myself however when I i run the code My answer is NULL. Which shouldn't be the case, the following new code is here (even though it is incorrect):

```
SELECT SUM(purchasedate = YEAR(CURDATE() AND MONTH(purchasedate) = 7))
     / SUM(purchasedate = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND MONTH(purchasedate) = 7)) 
FROM Sales
```

Secondly, in the case if there is a new artist with a new CD, it would be dividing against 0, and wouldn't include it in the result, however July 2011 being 0 and July 2012 398 for example, obviously this should be included in my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing the formatted date string as below:

```
   SELECT SUM(date_format(purchasedate, '%m-%Y') = CONCAT('07-',YEAR(CURDATE()))
         / SUM(date_format(purchasedate, '%m-%Y') = 
                         CONCAT('07-',YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
   FROM Sales
```